# Using signs to record new joiners to realm

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

The idea is to automatically place sign with name of a new player to the realm. When a new player joins command blocks give a new player starter kit and add him a tag "Started" to close the loop. I want to have a log/registry of who have joined.

I thought of adding a sign with new player name to a wall. Next new player will have sign added to the right of the previous sign.

The identification of new player, started kit and sign text is sorted, but how to move the sign coordinate by one with each new player at absense of variables and scoreboard not working for coords?

Comment: This feels slightly out of the scope of Minecraft Bedrock edition commands. You might be better off looking for an add-on solution.